# java: rethrowing trapped exception

Tags: java, exception

I want to trap a **SQLException**, send some mail and then send the exception on to the next target. I've subclassed as follows:

```
class myexception extends SQLException {
    public myexception( Throwable cause ) throws SQLException {
        super( cause );

        ... send mail ...

        throw new SQLException( cause );
    }
}
```

If I've wrapped an existing function that throws SQLException ('connect()' or it's ilk):

```
public void somecall() throws myexception {
   try {
      ... SQL call ...
   } catch( SQLException sqlException ) {
       throw new myexception( sqlException );
   }
}
```

can I **rethrow** the original SQLException or do I need to unpack it and create a new one? IE Is my class going to generate runtime errors when I call *throw new SQLException( cause );*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a much cleaner way to do what you're trying.

```
try {
    sqlCall();
} catch (SQLExcetion e) {
    sendMail();

    throw e;
}
```

You do not need to subclass `SQLException`.

Comment: Excellent point. In hindsight this is safer all around. (gets eraser out) - time to start (de)coding.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why it isn't possible, but you would need to catch the SQLException:

```
try{
    try{
        someCall();
    }
    catch(myException e) {

    }
}
catch(SQLException e) {
    // catches the thrown SQLException 
    //created by new myException(Throwable clause)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, Exceptions should not be used to implement business or framework logic (such as "send an e-mail when I get created")

The actual framework itself should be used to do this.

For example, if you are managing all of your software components inside an Inversion of Control (IoC) container such as spring and you want to do "something" (such as send an e-mail) every time a particular exception is thrown, you could use Aspect Orientated Programming techniques.

With such declarative constructs, you can target certain methods and intercept cases where an SQLException is thrown and then do your logic.

In the case of sending e-mails, I would personally create a queue or something so that execution of my main code is not held up while the e-mail is being sent